# LED lights border

Tags: html, css, frontend

I've created LED light border- http://codepen.io/anon/pen/grvYQp
It only works if the screen is set to a particular size. What changes should I make in the code so that it works with screen of any size?

HTML

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li class="bulb"></li>
    <li class="bulb"></li>
    <li class="bulb"></li>
    <li class="bulb"></li>
    <li class="bulb"></li>
    <li class="bulb"></li>
    <li class="bulb"></li>
    <li class="bulb"></li>
    <li class="bulb"></li>
    <li class="bulb"></li>

  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li class="bulb"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li class="bulb"></li>
  </ul>
    <ul>
    <li class="bulb"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li class="bulb"></li>
  </ul>
    <ul>
    <li class="bulb"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li class="bulb"></li>
  </ul>
    <ul>
    <li class="bulb"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li class="bulb"></li>
  </ul>
    <ul>
    <li class="bulb"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li class="bulb"></li>
  </ul>
    <ul>
    <li class="bulb"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li class="bulb"></li>
  </ul>
    <ul>
    <li class="bulb"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li class="bulb"></li>
  </ul>
    <ul>
    <li class="bulb"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li class="bulb"></li>
  </ul>
    <ul>
    <li class="bulb"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li class="bulb"></li>
  </ul>
    <ul>
    <li class="bulb"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li class="bulb"></li>
  </ul>
    <ul>
    <li class="bulb"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li class="bulb"></li>
  </ul>
    <ul>
    <li class="bulb"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li class="bulb"></li>
  </ul>
    <ul>
    <li class="bulb"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li class="bulb"></li>
  </ul>
    <ul>
    <li class="bulb"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li class="bulb"></li>
  </ul>
    <ul>
    <li class="bulb"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li class="bulb"></li>
  </ul>
    <ul>
    <li class="bulb"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li class="bulb"></li>
  </ul>
    <ul>
    <li class="bulb"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li class="bulb"></li>
  </ul>
    <ul>
    <li class="bulb"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li class="bulb"></li>
  </ul>
    <ul>
    <li class="bulb"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li class="bulb"></li>
  </ul>
    <ul>
    <li class="bulb"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li class="bulb"></li>
  </ul>
    <ul>
    <li class="bulb"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li class="bulb"></li>
  </ul>
    <ul>
    <li class="bulb"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li class="bulb"></li>
  </ul>
    <ul>
    <li class="bulb"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li class="bulb"></li>
  </ul>
    <ul>
    <li class="bulb"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li class="bulb"></li>
  </ul>
    <ul>
    <li class="bulb"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li class="bulb"></li>
  </ul>
    <ul>
    <li class="bulb"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li class="bulb"></li>
  </ul>
    <ul>
    <li class="bulb"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li class="bulb"></li>
  </ul>
    <ul>
    <li class="bulb"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li class="bulb"></li>
  </ul>
    <ul>
    <li class="bulb"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li class="bulb"></li>
  </ul>
    <ul>
    <li class="bulb"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li class="bulb"></li>
  </ul>
    <ul>
    <li class="bulb"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li class="bulb"></li>
  </ul>
    <ul>
    <li class="bulb"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li class="bulb"></li>
  </ul>
    <ul>
    <li class="bulb"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li class="bulb"></li>
  </ul>
    <ul>
    <li class="bulb"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li class="bulb"></li>
  </ul>
    <ul>
    <li class="bulb"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li class="bulb"></li>
  </ul>

  <ul>
    <li class="bulb"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li class="bulb"></li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li class="bulb"></li>
    <li class="bulb"></li>
    <li class="bulb"></li>
    <li class="bulb"></li>
    <li class="bulb"></li>
    <li class="bulb"></li>
    <li class="bulb"></li>
    <li class="bulb"></li>
    <li class="bulb"></li>
    <li class="bulb"></li>
  </ul>
```

CSS

```
@keyframes ledFlash {
  0% {
    background-size: 100% 100%;
  }
  50% {
    background-size: 160% 160%;
  }
  100% {
    background-size: 100% 100%;
  }
}

body {
  background: #000;
  padding: 10px;
}

div {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

ul {
  display: block;
  float: left;
}

ul li {
  margin: 2px;
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

ul .bulb {
  background-attachment: scroll;
  background-clip: border-box;
  background-color: transparent;
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(195, 255, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(41, 154, 11, 0) 100%);
  /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%, rgba(195, 255, 0, 1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(41, 154, 11, 0)));
  /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(195, 255, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(41, 154, 11, 0) 100%);
  /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(195, 255, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(41, 154, 11, 0) 100%);
  /* Opera 12+ */
  background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(195, 255, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(41, 154, 11, 0) 100%);
  /* IE10+ */
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(195, 255, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(41, 154, 11, 0) 100%);
  /* W3C */
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#c3ff00', endColorstr='#00299a0b', GradientType=1);
  /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  animation: ledFlash 1.5s infinite;
}
```

Comment: You would have to make the bulbs as border. Look for border-image

Comment: I don't want to use border image here

Comment: What's wrong with border-image? Is it the animation? You could easily create a basic GIF image

Comment: I agree with the border-image suggestion and the answer posted by @Aziz. Animating that many elements is rather processor intensive and makes for a not so smooth animation (at least for me.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a pure CSS approach using `border-image` on a psuedo-selector (`:before`) for the animation.

```css
/* demo stuff */

body {
  background:#000;
  color:#FFF;
  padding:3em;
  text-align: center;
}

div {border:1px dashed #666;}

/* container */

.ledborder {
  padding:34px;
  position:relative;
  line-height:34px;
}

.ledborder:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
  content: ""; z-index:-1;
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  /* the border image */
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 34px;
  -moz-border-image: url(http://puu.sh/ocvuq/d01cc89c15.png) 34 round;
  -webkit-border-image: url(http://puu.sh/ocvuq/d01cc89c15.png) 34 round;
  -o-border-image: url(http://puu.sh/ocvuq/d01cc89c15.png) 34 round;
  border-image: url(http://puu.sh/ocvuq/d01cc89c15.png) 34 round;
  animation: ledFlash 1.5s infinite;
}

/* animation */

@keyframes ledFlash {
  50% { opacity:.6; }
}
```

```html
<div class="ledborder">
  I am surrounded by light!
</div>
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/3pdesrL0/1/

I feel that using that many HTML elements is unnecessary. This solution is simple and `line-height: 34px` ensures the border image is consistent (no stretches).

Comment: It solves most of my problem. What is the red dotted line for? I can make it  of the same color as the background so that it becomes invisible, right? Also, can I adjust the size of bulbs for different screens or will it remain fixed?

Comment: the red border is just to show the bounding box, you can remove it. the bulbs will span the entire width/height of container, test it and check how it behaves in different screen sizes. If you want to reduce the actual size you can create a smaller border-image then change the values to match the new image size

Comment: Thanks! I'll make some changes to it

Answer (score 1):

Is `javascript` an option? Then you could hide some of columns when size is small:

```
 function adjustLeds() {
    var bulbWidth = $('ul:eq(0)').width();
    var availableWidth = $('body').width() - 15 /*div margin*/ ;
    var toremove = $('ul').length - Math.floor(availableWidth / bulbWidth);
    if (toremove > 0)
      $('ul').show().slice(1, toremove + 1).hide()
  }

  $(function() {
    adjustLeds();
    $(window).on('resize', adjustLeds);
  })
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xVYxxM

Comment: Interesting solution, however, when you resize the window (enlarging) the animations become inconsistent: http://i.imgur.com/wmpDTFh.gifv

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting another answer because it is a totally different method:

**Multiple CSS backgrounds**

Basically, use an animated GIF image and have and repeat it in 4 layers, a layer for each side: top, right, bottom and left.

In the past this used to be done through 4 containers, but with the introduction of [CSS multiple-backgrounds](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Background_and_Borders/Using_CSS_multiple_backgrounds), it is much easier:

```css
/* demo stuff */

body {
  background:#000;
  color:#FFF;
  padding:3em;
  text-align: center;
}

div {border:1px dashed red;}

/* container */

.ledborder {
  margin:0 auto;
  padding:34px;
  position:relative;
  line-height:34px;
  background:
    url(http://i.imgur.com/bkmui6S.gif) repeat-y,
    url(http://i.imgur.com/bkmui6S.gif) repeat-y right,
    url(http://i.imgur.com/bkmui6S.gif) repeat-x,
    url(http://i.imgur.com/bkmui6S.gif) repeat-x left bottom;
}
```

```html
<div class="ledborder">
  I am surrounded by light!
</div>
```

There is an obvious **drawback** to this solution, the bulbs can overlap each other if the width is not a multiple of the image's size, I solved this using jQuery:

```js
// jquery plugin written by OPOPO
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15040153/css-100-width-with-steps-per-20px

$.fn.widthStep = function(step)
{
    var width = $(this).width();
    $(this).css('max-width', width - width%step);
}

$('.ledborder').widthStep(34);

// recalculate max-width on resize
$( window ).resize(function() {
  $('.ledborder').removeAttr("style");
  $('.ledborder').widthStep(34);
});
```

```css
/* demo stuff */

body {
  background:#000;
  color:#FFF;
  padding:3em;
  text-align: center;
}

div {border:1px dashed red;}

/* container */

.ledborder {
  margin:0 auto;
  padding:34px;
  position:relative;
  line-height:34px;
  background:
    url(http://i.imgur.com/bkmui6S.gif) repeat-y,
    url(http://i.imgur.com/bkmui6S.gif) repeat-y right,
    url(http://i.imgur.com/bkmui6S.gif) repeat-x,
    url(http://i.imgur.com/bkmui6S.gif) repeat-x left bottom;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ledborder">
  I am surrounded by light!
</div>
```

The function basically forces the container to have a max-width that is a multiple of the image width (34).

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/ot7sv5pz/

Comment: On a second thought, this could probably done with a static image instead of an animated GIF and placed in a pseudo-selector for the native CSS animation.